# MongoDb find by date when stored as a string

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

In my MongoDb (using Mongoose) I'm storing dates as a string in utc and ISO format.
Now I want to do a search for records by date but I can't figure out how.

```
Data.find()
   .$where(function() {
      return new Date(this.timeStamp).getTime() > new Date('2016-1-1').getTime();
   })
   .exec(function(err, wData) {
      if(err) {return next(err);}
      res.json(wData);
   });
```

Problem is the $where removes all general functions for some reason and "getTime()" is not a method of the object.

How would I go about doing this without changing the schema to store a 'Date'.

Edit: I have also tried Date.parse(). And ' console' does not exist in the $where either if I try output anything.

Edit2:
Here's my Schema, I don't have access to my Db at the moment so I can't give a sample doc. However, I am using the data already (without the $where, it just returns everything I have) and the date formats are fine and convert into Date objects correctly on the front end.

```
var WeatherData = new mongoose.Schema({
    timeStamp: String,
    lightLevel: Number,
    temperature: Number,
    pressure: Number,
    humidity: Number,
    windSpeed: Number,
    windDirection: Number
});
```

Edit3:
Although the problem is solved, I'm interested in any other methods that don't involve 'RegExp'

Comment: why in the second `getTime` you are not calling the function? is it a typo?

Comment: Yeah was a typo when asking question. Doesn't fix the problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query dates using regex, try:

```
WheaterData.find( {timeStamp: new RegExp("^YYYY-MM-DD","i") } )
```

It will return all documents matching the given day in YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: This works, but any chance you can explain how "^YYYY-MM-DD" works? What does ^ do? How would I do date ranges with this?

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out.
WeatherData.find({
        timeStamp: new RegExp("^(2016-02-18|2016-02-19)", "i")
    })

Comment: The ^ operator will match on the beginning of the string. Using it will make the comparison faster and less error prone.